# Pyspark RDD to DataFrame with Enforced Schema: Value Error

Tags: pyspark, schema, rdd

I am working with pyspark with a schema commensurate with that shown at the end of this post (note the nested lists, unordered fields), initially imported from Parquet as a DataFrame.  Fundamentally, the issue that I am running into is the inability to process this data as a RDD, and then convert back to a DataFrame. (I have reviewed several related posts, but I still cannot tell where I am going wrong.)

Trivially, the following code works fine (as one would expect):

```
schema = deepcopy(tripDF.schema)
tripRDD = tripDF.rdd
tripDFNew = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tripRDD, schema)
tripDFNew.take(1)
```

Things do not work when I need to map the RDD (as would be the case to add a field, for instance).

```
schema = deepcopy(tripDF.schema)
tripRDD = tripDF.rdd
def trivial_map(row):
    rowDict = row.asDict()
    return pyspark.Row(**rowDict)
tripRDDNew = tripRDD.map(lambda row: trivial_map(row))
tripDFNew = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tripRDDNew, schema)
tripDFNew.take(1)
```

The code above gives the following exception where XXX is a stand-in for an integer, which changes from run to run (e.g., I've seen 1, 16, 23, etc.):

```
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-
1.cdh5.8.3.p1967.2057/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 546, in 
toInternal
raise ValueError("Unexpected tuple %r with StructType" % obj)
ValueError: Unexpected tuple XXX with StructType`
```

Given this information, **is there a clear error in the second block of code**? (I note that tripRDD is of class rdd.RDD while tripRDDNew is of class rdd.PipelinedRDD, but I don't think this should be a problem.)  (I also note that the schema for tripRDD is not sorted by field name, while the schema for tripRDDNew is sorted by field name. Again, I don't see why this would be a problem.)

Schema:

```
root
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar_2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar_3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- baz_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- baz_2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- baz_3: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar_4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- baz_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- baz_2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- baz_3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- qux: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- corge: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- uier: integer (nullable = true)`
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the post, the original schema has fields that are not alphabetically ordered.  Therein lies the problem. The use of .asDict() in the mapping function orders the fields of the resulting RDD.  The field order of tripRDDNew is in conflict with schema at the call to createDataFrame.  The ValueError results from an attempt to parse one of the integer fields (i.e., qux, corge, or uier in the example) as a StructType.

(As an aside: It is a little surprising that createDataFrame requires the schema fields to have the same order as the RDD fields. You should either need consistent field names OR consistent field ordering, but requiring both seems like overkill.)

(As a second aside: The existence of non-alphabetical fields in the DataFrame is somewhat abnormal.  For instance, sc.parallelize() will automatically order fields alphabetically when distributing the data structure.  It seems like the fields should be ordered when importing the DataFrame from the parquet file. It might be interesting to investigate why this is not the case.)